# how to convert float to string correctly in avr c

Tags: c, avr, atmel, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

I need to convert a float value to a string in my avr project. Therefore I tried it with the following code:

```
char buf[10];
float emg1 = 33.42;
sprintf(buf, "%f", emg1);
uart_puts(buf);
```

But the output is only a "?". I tried to change the char format from %f to %g but I only got "?".

Is there another way to simply convert float to string, or can somebody tell me where the mistake is?

Comment: Maybe your printf implementation doesn't support %f. Did you double check with e.g. `sprintf(buf, "%d", 123)` just to be sure that the problem is not elsewhere?

Comment: I don't see the issue with string conversion. Sometimes due to sync error bits are wrongly interpreted.

Comment: with %d and a int it works

Comment: @kaan5353 then clearly your printf implementation doesn't support %f. That should be somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: `-Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm` has to be enabled for `float`, as per `avr` [doc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html#gaa3b98c0d17b35642c0f3e4649092b9f1).

Comment: Tip: `sprintf(buf, "%f", emg1);` is not certainly enough info to convert the string back to the same `float`.  Better as `sprintf(buf, "%.8e", emg1);` or `sprintf(buf, "%.9g", emg1);` with a larger buffer (about 17+).